# multiple input types in css only setting first one

Tags: css

im trying to set css on multiple input types (text, password etc)

using:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=submit] {
    width:200px;
}
```

but its only setting the style on the first on (in this case `type=text`)

how can i make it set on all of them rather than just the first one

and also, without having to do:

```
input[type=text] {
    width:200px;
}

input[type=password] {
    width:200px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reordering them to be sure it really is the first one, and not type=text specifically?

Comment: try this with "" `input[type="text"]
{}`

Comment: it works fine: `input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=submit] { width:200px; }` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9tCXX/1/)

Comment: Probably some other ruleset interferes with this one. Any ruleset with more specific selectors would do that.

Comment: There has to be some other rules that interfer. What you have works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/taC8B/

Comment: Put width:200px !important; and try again, It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Your original code works fine. What browser are you using? [http://liveweave.com/bBIaPZ](http://liveweave.com/bBIaPZ). Tested in Firefox, Safari, Chrome in both Mac and Windows.